# Windows 10; permission on remote computer

Tags: remote-access, remote

From computer A, I can open files on computer B but cannot write to them. I even logged on A as an administrator whose user name also appeared on B. Still, couldn't modify files.

All the hard disks on B are shared and Administrator/Administrators have full control on them (on B). This is on the top level. I didn't change any permissions on the sub-folders. Do I need to have sub-folders inherit the properties of the top folder in order to write to files on them?

Comment: The Administrator user group on Machine A will not have Administrator permissions on Machine B.  You have to grant permissions to both Machine A and Machine B Administrators.

Comment: How? I can't find a detailed instruction on the net. Maybe I just can't understand the articles I found.